# Python comparison operators

Tags: python-2.7, comparison-operators

I have two values e.g a=972 and b=11188.
I want to get the details of all entries from a tab delimited text file which lies in between both numbers. The python comparison operators <= and >= are returning wrong results.

I have used the `<=` and `>=` operators in the if statement.

```
if l1[3]<="18188" >="900" and l1[2]=="1":
```

and it is returning nothing.
when I write

```
if l1[3]<="18188":
```

it returns "18166 and 11188 as output". I ideally this if function must return "11188 ,972 and 3632".

This is the tab delimited file.

```
SRR6298199.1    16  1   3632    0   50M32S  *   0   0   AACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCC   !!""""!"!"!"!!"!!!""""""!!!""""!""  NM:i:1  AS:i:48 XS:i:47
SRR6298199.10   0   1   972 0   40M274S *   0   0   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCAATTTGAA !"""'$""!"!"""" NM:i:0  AS:i:40 XS:i:40 XP:Z:3,+18166143,41S36M237S,0,0;
SRR6298199.10   0   1   18166   0   41S36M237S  *   0   0   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCAATTT    !"""!#!#$#$"!""""   NM:i:0  AS:i:36 XS:i:34 XP:Z:2,+9723273,40M274S,0,0;
SRR6298199.11   16  1   11188   0   1841S9M *   0   0   GACCAGTATCGGGCCGGCATAAGCCTCGAATTTCACCAGCA   !!!!!!""!#!"%%&)(%-//.//,".,.+.-..&!    NM:i:18 AS:i:81 XS:i:81
```

Here is the complete code.. please figure out why this code is not returning true results.

```
# EXTRACTING THE DETAILS OF READS ALIGNED ON CHR_1 
fr=open("Sample.txt","r")
z=fr.read()
bz=z.split("\n")
temp1=[]
for bases in bz:
    temp1.append(bases.split("\t"))
cc1=[]
se=[] #READ NAMES ALIGNED ON CHR_1
chr2=[] #READ NAMES ALIGNED ON CHR_2
for l1 in temp1:
 if l1[3]<="18188" >="900" and l1[2]=="1":
     #print(l1[3])
        #cc1.append("@"+str(l1[0])+"\t"+"length="+str(len(l1[9]))+"\n"+l1[9]+"\n"+"+"+l1[0]+"\t"+"length="+str(len(l1[9]))+"\n"+l1[10])
    cc1.append("@"+str(l1[0])+" "+"/1"+"\n"+"+"+"\n"+l1[9])       
print(cc1)
```

I expect the output of `if l1[3]<="18188" >="900" and l1[2]=="1":` to be

```
['SRR6298199.1', '16', '1', '3632', '0', '50M32S', '*', '0', '0', 'AACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCC', '!!""""!"!"!"!!"!!!""""""!!!""""!""', 'NM:i:1', 'AS:i:48', 'XS:i:47']
['SRR6298199.10', '0', '1', '972', '0', '40M274S', '*', '0', '0', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCAATTTGAA', '!"""\'$""!"!""""', 'NM:i:0', 'AS:i:40', 'XS:i:40', 'XP:Z:3,+18166143,41S36M237S,0,0;']
['SRR6298199.11', '16', '1', '11188', '0', '1841S9M', '*', '0', '0', 'GACCAGTATCGGGCCGGCATAAGCCTCGAATTTCACCAGCA', '!!!!!!""!#!"%%&)(%-//.//,".,.+.-..&!', 'NM:i:18', 'AS:i:81', 'XS:i:81']
['SRR6298199.10', '0', '1', '18166', '0', '41S36M237S', '*', '0', '0', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCAATTT', '!"""!#!#$#$"!""""', 'NM:i:0', 'AS:i:36', 'XS:i:34', 'XP:Z:2,+9723273,40M274S,0,0;']
```

but aforementioned if statement is returning `[]`, an empty list

Comment: `l1[3]<="18188" >="900"` is equivalent to `l1[3]<="18188"  and "18188" >="900"`.  `"18188" >="900"` is always false, so this will never be true.  What condition are you trying to test for with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) you misuse / misorder the comparisonoperators

```
if l1[3]<= "18188" >="900" and l1[2]=="1":  # always false becase "1..." is never >= "9.."
```

should most probably be

```
if "900"<= l1[3] <="18188" and l1[2]=="1":
```

2) you use lexicografical comparison to compare numbers - this will fail because in lexicographical comparisons `"9"` is bigger then `"1111111"`

**You can fix both errors using correct comparison syntax and float-values for comparison:**

```
if 900 <= float(l1[3]) <= 18188 and l1[2]=="1":
```